# While loop does not loop in KSH script

Tags: csh

While loop is iterating only once while reading from the text file
Here is the code

while IFS= read -r line
do
    var=`echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $3}'`
   var2=`ssh samwgt@prdwgt31 "cd /$path && cksum $var"` 
    if [[ "$line" = $var2 ]]
    then
        echo "$line: MATCHED " >> $target_path/output_file
    else
        echo "$line: NOT MATCHED" >> $target_path/output_file
    fi

done <"$source_path"

Please suggest what needs to be Done

Comment: The question is not clear.Kindly rephrase your question.

Comment: Your title mentions "KSH", but you tagged this "csh". Which is it? Also please format the code as such (highlight and use the `{ }` button)

Comment: Its a KSH Script,

Comment: I got the problem, the problem SSH command is breaking the loop and i am not able to overcome that problem, please advice